# It is possible to return custom data to Kafka Producer

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am learning kafka and I want to split my app to 2 microservices. 
First save all incoming messages from KafkaConsumer to database and select entity by given id. 
Second provide REST api to save and get entities.
Interaction between them provided with kafka.
How can I receive stored ID from db in REST api with kafka? 
Here is sample code of producer which calls on POST request.

```
 public void sendToKafka(MyObject myobject) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    LOGGER.info("sending payload='{}' to topic='{}'", myobject, myTopic);
    byte[] bytes = parseObjectToByte(myobject);
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, byte[]>> resultFuture = kafkaTemplate.send(topicSave, bytes);
    SendResult<String, byte[]> result = resultFuture.get();
    LOGGER.info(result.toString());
}
```

and Consumer, which save myObject to database

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.mytopic}")
public void saveMyObject(byte[] value) {
    MyObject myobject = parseToMyObject(value);
    LOGGER.info("received myobject='{}'", myobject);
    MyObject myobjectSaved = myObjectRepository.insert(myobject);
}
```

I'm using spring-kafka with spring-boot. 
Rest api has 2 methods:
POST  - save myObject
Get - return saved object by id.
It is possible do it with kafka or i must connect this microservices directly? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but if you want to send a message to kafka, and wait for this message to be consumed and handled by some microservice which would then return some information (a primary key) to the sender of the message you cannot do that without adding more to your architecture.

A message sent to kafka is "fire and forget" and from the sender point of view you know nothing about what will happen with this message (if, when, how often, and by how many consumers it will be consumed.)

In your scenario, the consumer microservice could also send messages with the primary key in another kafka topic, that you would consume if you need that information.

Remember Kafka serves to decouple your architecture and to introduce asynchronous message handling, if you need to synchronously have a response from a consumer you are probably using the wrong solution.